# How to get user's all time rank in reputation league from API?

Tags: feature-request, api, reputation-leagues

I am looking at the api to get a user , but could not find any property which tells me the user's all time/monthly rank in reputation league. Is there another endpoint which provides this information ?

This is the one i tried.
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/40413?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow

It would be nice if this was part of the user api endpoints :) It would be super awesome if we have an api endpoint to get complete data for reputation league.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this isn't available. Wish it was though!